# Delphi Now() function returns a wrong value

Tags: delphi, datetime, delphi-2007

I have the DirectX-based application. And recently I found that `Now()` function returns a wrong value when being called from within the main loop of my graphics engine. It gives one value being called before engine initialized and different one (usually differs 2-3 minutes back or forward) when being called in my application when graphics is started.

I found that `Now()` function is a wrapper for Windows API `GetLocalTime()` function. Anyone can point out what can  affect the return value of this very function? I heavily use `timeGetTime()` function in the main loop of my app, can it be the source of problem? Also I need to use `CheckSyncronize()` function in the main loop...

Any ideas? I'm out of clues... :(

code of the main loop:

```
    procedure Td2dCore.System_Run;
    var
        l_Msg: TMsg;
        l_Point: TPoint;
        l_Rect : TRect;
        l_Finish: Boolean;
    begin
        if f_WHandle = 0 then
        begin
            System_Log('Engine was not started!');
            Exit;
        end;

        if not Assigned(f_OnFrame) then
        begin
            System_Log('Frame function is not assigned!');
            Exit;
        end;

        // MAIN LOOP
        l_Finish := False;
        while not l_Finish do
        begin
            // dispatch messages
            if PeekMessage(l_Msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) then
            begin
                if l_Msg.message = WM_QUIT then
                    l_Finish := True;
                DispatchMessage(l_Msg);
                Continue;
            end;

            GetCursorPos(l_Point);
            GetClientRect(f_WHandle, l_Rect);
            MapWindowPoints(f_WHandle, 0, l_Rect, 2);
            f_MouseOver := f_MouseCaptured or (PtInRect(l_Rect, l_Point) and (WindowFromPoint(l_Point) = f_WHandle));
            if f_Active or f_DontSuspend then
            begin
                repeat
                    f_DeltaTicks := timeGetTime - f_Time0;
                    if f_DeltaTicks <= f_FixedDelta then
                        Sleep(1);
                until f_DeltaTicks > f_FixedDelta;
                //if f_DeltaTicks >= f_FixedDelta then
                begin
                    f_DeltaTime := f_DeltaTicks / 1000.0;

                    // if delay was too big, count it as if where was no delay
                    // (return from suspended state for instance)
                    if f_DeltaTime > 0.2 then
                        if f_FixedDelta > 0 then
                            f_DeltaTime := f_FixedDelta / 1000.0
                        else
                            f_DeltaTime := 0.01;

                    f_Time := f_Time + f_DeltaTime;

                    f_Time0 := timeGetTime;

                    if(f_Time0 - f_Time0FPS < 1000) then
                        Inc(f_FPSCount)
                    else
                    begin
                        f_FPS := f_FPSCount;
                        f_FPSCount := 0;
                        f_Time0FPS := f_Time0;
                    end;

                    f_OnFrame(f_DeltaTime, l_Finish);
                    if Assigned(f_OnRender) then
                        f_OnRender();
                    ClearQueue;
                    {
                    if (not f_Windowed) and (f_FixedFPS = D2D_FPS_VSYNC) then
                        Sleep(1);
                    }
                end;
                {
                else
                    if (f_FixedDelta > 0) and (f_DeltaTicks+3 < f_FixedDelta) then
                        Sleep(1);
                }
            end
            else
                Sleep(1);
            CheckSynchronize;
        end;
    end;
```

the Now() is called somewhere in `f_OnFrame()` function.

Comment: Does it misbehave on all machines? Can you reproduce this in a small sample program?

Comment: Yes. Actually I received this error as a bug report. I think I can make a small program but it will involve linking of my graphic engine...

Comment: I've posted a main loop code in the top message.

Comment: Can you reproduce the behaviour? Does it misbehave on all machines?

Comment: Yes. It is misbehave on a few machines I could check it on...

Comment: Are the processors multicore and of same architecture on those ? can frequences be locked ?

Comment: Is there threading involved here? I can only imagine that there is a sequencing issue, that means that the code is supposed to be run on one order, but somehow is actually going in another order. If the Now function was as erratic as you say, it would be happening all over. I use it a lot in heavily threaded code, and have never seen such behaviour.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally I've found the solution. I needed to specify th `D3DCREATE_FPU_PRESERVE` flag when creating a D3D device by `D3D.CreateDevice`.

Otherwise, without that flag, all floating point operations are performed with single precision. As the `TDateTime` is a simple `Double`, and `Now()` functions is consist of simple addition of date value to time value, it all get messed up by DirectX "smart" override.

Problem solved. It was a tricky one indeed. :)

Answer (score 2):

I use to run into these issues with OpenGL and the simulator and MapObjects.  The timing sequence was found to be the differences between the equipment.  Here is two links that might shed some light onto the subject:

http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/delphi-high-performance-timer-tstopwatch.htm
Zarko Gajic's article helped with the timer that I had to build for a serial interface.  I used a variation of this code example to pull data for a tank sensor.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644900%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
This is the microsoft information on using high end timers in your software.  Generally timers will cycle out and be off sync.  This article goes into two timers, the High-Resolution Timer and the Waitable Timer Objects.  The High-Resolution is the timer variant that I used for the simulator.

Comment: While this maybe required as further fine tuning, it does not seem to be relevant. The question complains that 'SYSTEMTIME' slips between different calls. It won't use different chips through successive calls. Or possibly I didn't understood the question..

Comment: I can't see how these links can be related to adjacent calls to `Now` returning values minutes apart.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I've understood from the code, you are making decisions on

```
              f_DeltaTicks := timeGetTime - f_Time0;
```

f_Time0 variable is initialized at a later stage in the loop.

```
                f_Time0 := timeGetTime;
```

there might be a simple bug, that the f_Time0 is not initialized the way you want/require on the first entrance into the loop.

Comment: In fact, no.  There is no bug. Below I've posted a solution I found. But thanks for help! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using DirectX, it's better to turn on math accuracy when needed and turn it off when there's no need.

```
uses Math;


var pm: TFPUPrecisionMode;
begin
   pm: = GetPrecisionMode;
   try
     SetPrecisionMode (pmExtended)
.
.
.
   finally
     SetPrecisionMode (pm);
   end
end;
```

Direct X and some graphics card drivers require this and may throw an error: Invalid floating point operation